# New message alert

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Just like stackoverflow and facebook do tell of the number of new messages you've got, please which jquery tool do they use? I have been playing around with toastr but it appears that toastr notification is bigger and therefore not the tool facebook and stackoverflow, and codeproject do use to notify users. Please help me out on the name.

Comment: "Which jQuery tool do they use?" Why do you assume it's jQuery? And you know that jQuery is *not* synonymous with JavaScript, right?

Comment: I just assume its jquery but if it is not please, help me out

Comment: More likely they use a model binding framework like knockoutjs. Or even more likely, code that uses long polling and web sockets

Comment: Well, it sounds new to me. Is there any sample on this?

Comment: If you're using .Net then take a look at SignalR.

Comment: You could go for push notification services for web. Chrome now has native support for web push notification.